# error handling in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, exception

First, i found out the cakephp is using `throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid'));` to handle their error page. which indicate error page to `app/views/error/error.ctp`. 
Now my question is any other solution to handle the error of NotFound Page in every controller actions other then keep using throw new NotFoundException? 
example : i had 10 controller and each controller had 10 same action = `/controllers/main`. I dont want call 10 times in those actions.
any method to solve it ? perhaps do something function in `app/appcontrollers`, maybe `afterFilter()` ?

Comment: Please clarify the problem `I dont want call 10 times in those actions.` - what does that mean?

Comment: dont u see that i wrote i had 10 main actions in 10 different controller ? so if i want to handle error every controller main action. i need do 10 times. right ?

Comment: sweat. example i had UserControllers,NewsControllers, ProjectControllers, inside every controller i had public function main( $id = null) . if i wan throw exception i need throw in every function main in controller. is it this so hard to understand ? i just want write 1 line code to let 10 controller to let 10 controller use. instead writing in all controller

Comment: what's hard to understand (edit the question - don't use comments to clarify your question) is why throwing an exception (one line of code) is a problem. You don't show any code so it's not possible to say "you can just do this instead". Good luck :).

Comment: Please read the manual. It's states how to make custom error or exception handlers. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html and http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html. You could use the afterFilter to catch the NotFoundException before Cake does itself. But I would just throw a custom error and catch the way the docs describe. That's a much better design